# make django model field read only or disable in admin while saving the object first time

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-admin-actions

I want to disable the few fields from model in django admin while saving initially.

```
"<input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">"
```

like this.

My model is:

```
class Blogmodel(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to=get_photo_storage_path, null=True, blank=False)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    n_comments = models.IntegerField()
```

i want to disable the "headline" and "n_comments".
i tried it in admin.py file, but its not disabling the fields on initial saving. But for editing the fields its working, it making the fields read only.

in admin.py

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude=("headline ",)
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ['headline']
        else:
            return []
```

Headling getting disabled but for edit only. i want to disable it at the time of object creation. i.e. first save.
can anyone guide me for this?

Comment: Why are you not using readonly_fields property instead?

Comment: it will work for editing the objects not for creating the object first time.

Comment: It will work for both if you are not overwriting `get_readonly_fields`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to make the field read-only during creation you should do it the other way round:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj is None:
        return ['headline']
    return []
```

Comment: it worked thanks a lot. But its not showing the input box disabled.

Comment: hay its not working for edit!!. While editing its not disabled.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question, thought you only want to disable it for creating... otherwise just always `return ['headline']`... No need for the If-clause...

Answer (score 85):

There is no need to override `get_readonly_fields`. Simplest solution would be:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude=("headline ",)
    readonly_fields=('headline', )
```

When using `readonly_fields` you can't override `get_readonly_fields`, because default implementation reads readonly_fields variable. So overriding it only if you have to have some logic on deciding which field should be read-only at time.

Comment: I have no idea why people are not using your simple suggestion here

Comment: This is the way to go!

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 11):

Just do editable=False, while adding the field in the model

```
headline = models.CharField(max_length=255,editable=False)
```

It wont be editable and you cannot see the field from admin panel, but you can add values to them from a method within the model

Answer (score 5):

**Other way is:**

```
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)

        if obj is None:

            form.base_fields["my_field"].disabled = True

        return form
```